# How to set a variable inside `if` in Sass?

Tags: if-statement, sass

Is it possibel to set a variable inside the parentheses of an `if` statement in Sass?

I've tried to:

```
@function test() {
  @if ($variable: true) {        <<<< line 67
    @return $variable;
  }
}
```

And it says: `Undefined variable: "$variable". on line 67 at column 8`.

I've tried also to place `=` instead `:`, but the result is the same.

Comment: Where is your `$variable` defined? If you define it globally outside your function, it should be found when you call the function... (Also, it is `$variable == true` to check true/false in sass). So actually, what is the goal here? What are you trying to base your return value on?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to set the variable inside the parentheses of an `if`, and not how to use it.

Comment: You cannot set them inside the if statement itself, but you can set a variable right before. But again, if `$variable` _does not exist anywhere before_, you cannot use it. Also, if you are setting the variable anyhow then you know how your if statement will evaluate so why would you need to do this in an if? I have a feeling that you are looking for a solution to a problem that could be defined differently and solved more elegantly.

Comment: I want to do this because I don't want to set it before and include an extra line in the function. That's why I wanted to know if it was possible somehow.

Comment: It is actually advised not to set variable inside `if` statements (linters will not like it) mostly because it makes it less obvious when reading the code what it is doing. Also, SASS is a precompiler so having more code there has no effect on your output. But for the actual problem, no, you cannot solve it as such.

Comment: It's repetitive to set it, check it and return it. It seems that something is not right. But thanks for the comments!